# Only clicked item visible and hide the pervious items in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, show-hide, onitemclicklistener

I have `ImageView` inside of an item in a `RecyclerView`. Every time I click on an item, I want the image to become visible and the previous clicked item's image becomes invisible.

```
public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView image_view;
    private TextView text_view_name;
    private TextView text_view_abilities;
    private ImageView heart_image_view;

    public MyHolder(@NonNull final View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        image_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        text_view_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        text_view_abilities = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_abilities);
        heart_image_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.heart_image_view);
        heart_image_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
        heart_image_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (listener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    listener.onItemClick(position);
                    heart_image_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item_layout, viewGroup, false);
    MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(v, mlistener);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int position) {

    Item item = myList.get(position);
    myHolder.text_view_name.setText(item.getTitle());

    stringArray = item.getAbilitiesObj();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.size(); i++) {
        try {
            builder.append(stringArray.get(i));
            builder.append(", ");

        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        myHolder.text_view_abilities.setText(builder);
    }
    if (myHolder.image_view != null) {
        String photoUrl = item.getImageUrl();
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(photoUrl).into(myHolder.image_view);
    }
}
```

In `MyHolder` class where `item.setOnClick`, I set the clicked item image visible but then every time I click on another item, the image of the new item becomes visible and the image of the previous item does not get invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have another array of integers in your adapter to keep track of the items which is clicked. At first, initialize the array of integers with all ones.

```
// Define an array like the following in your adapter 
private int[] selectedItems = new int[yourDataList.size()]; // Initialize the array to have the same size as your data list.
```

Then initialize the array with all ones. Try having a function like this in your adapter.

```
private void initializeSeledtedItems() {
    for(int item : selectedItems) item = 1;
}
```

Now in your `onBindViewHolder`, set the visibility of the `ImageView` in your `RecyclerView` items based on the value found in the `selectedItems` array.

```
if(selectedItems[position] == 1) heart_image_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else heart_image_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In the `onClickListener` modify the `selectedItems` array as such that, only the item selected has the value one and all the others have zeros. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged` to take your changes into effect.

```
private void setSelectedItem(int position) {
    for(int i = 0; i < selectedItems.length(); i++) {
        if(i == position) selectedItems[i] = 1;
        else selectedItems[i] = 0;
    }
} 

itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (listener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                setSelectedItem(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for helping . i did all of what you saying but the app crashed with this error  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: This is just a pseudo code. Just get your list and put the size of that list while initializing your array. Make sure that you have initialized the list being passed in the adapter as well.

Comment: sorry my friend, it seems that is always make item in first raw visable.how do i made him make the clicked item only visable?

Comment: The idea is to keep the track of the clicked item in a separate array. So that you can show/hide based on the value. If the main idea is clear to you, I think you can figure it out yourself. :)

Comment: hmm , i got the main idea but still not succeed to make it the way i need :( where do i need to use initializeSeledtedItems()?

Comment: In the constructor of your adapter.

Comment: public MyHeroAdapter(Context context, List<Item> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
        mContext = context;
        selectedItems = new int[myList.size()];
        initializeSeledtedItems();
            }

Comment: this is my constractur of the adpter now

Comment: Yap, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

My code is for setting Visibility  on recycler view's item , when you click on recycler views item it set VISIBLE  on that particular item and INVISIBLE on other items.

this code works for me for setting visibility on clicked item and hiding previous icon.

initialize

```
     int selecteditem =0;
```

onBindViewHolder

```
   if(selecteditem==position){
        holder.icSelect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        holder.icSelect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }



     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           selecteditem=position;
           holder.icselect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           notifyDataSetChanged();


       }
   });
```

i uploaded image for basic idea .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wDQO.png)